# Merge separate footnotes into text

Tags: macros, footnotes

A text (written by someone else) has numbered footnote insertion points:

```
Text text1) text text text2) text text text.3) Text ...
```

The actual footnote-texts are in a second file:

```
1) text of note one
2) text of note two
3) text of note three
...
```

Manually putting each note where it belongs would be a nuisance; using endnotes instead of footnotes is unfortunately not an option.
Using `\footnotemark[num]` and `\footnotetext[num]` gives me the right numbering but not the right distribution over the pages.

I was wondering whether I could define one numbered macro per note (e.g. `\newcommand{\sepfootnote1}{\footnote{text of note one}}` and calling each macro at the appropriate point in the text but as macro names may not contain numbers this wouldn't be possible with a simple RegEx.

Is there another way to make LaTeX do the tedious work?

Comment: Cf my follow-up question: [Print only existing footnotes / suppress empty footnotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33590/print-only-existing-footnotes-suppress-empty-footnotes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If doing text substitutions is not a problem, you can prepend `\printfootnote` to all expressions such as `1)` or `2)` in the text and `\definefootnote` in the footnote file; append also `\endfootnote` at the end of each footnote text. Then

```
\def\printfootnote#1){\footnote{\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname}}
\def\definefootnote#1) #2\endfootnote{%
  \expandafter\def\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname{#2}}
\input{footnotefile}
```

(where `footnotefile.tex` is the file containing the footnote text) should do the trick, at least if the footnote file is not extremely big.

Here is `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\printfootnote#1){\footnote{\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname}}
\def\definefootnote#1) #2\endfootnote{%
  \expandafter\def\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname{#2}}
\input{footnotefile}

\begin{document}
Text text\printfootnote1) text text text\printfootnote2) text text text.\printfootnote3) Text
\end{document}
```

And here is `footnotefile.tex`:

```
\definefootnote1) First footnote\endfootnote
\definefootnote2) Second footnote\endfootnote
\definefootnote3) Third footnote\endfootnote
```

Note: use `\def` and *not* `\newcommand`, as the trick involves delimited arguments.