# Print only existing footnotes / suppress empty footnotes

Tags: macros, footnotes

This is a follow-up to my earlier question [Merge separate footnotes into text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28448/merge-separate-footnotes-into-text).

I now have a similar case, where I need to check whether there actually *are* footnotes relating to a particular number:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\mylips}[1]{\printfootnote#1 \lipsum[#1]}

\def\printfootnote#1{\footnote{\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname}}
\def\definefootnote#1 #2\endfootnote{%
  \expandafter\def\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname{#2}}
\input{footnotefile}


\begin{document}
 \mylips{1}
 \mylips{2}
 \mylips{3}
 \mylips{4}
 \mylips{5}
 \mylips{6}
 \mylips{7}
\end{document}
```

`footnotefile.tex` would be

```
\definefootnote1 Some footnote\endfootnote
\definefootnote3 Another footnote\endfootnote
\definefootnote7 And another footnote\endfootnote
```

The challenge is that I don't want the empty notes to appear at all.

How would I write a test for whether the result of a certain `\printfootnote\arabic{somecounter}` will be empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your `\printfootnote` should check whether the footnote was defined:

```
\def\printfootnote#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname\relax % by default \csname FOO\endcsname is \relax
 \stepcounter{footnote}\else % Even if we do not produce footnote, we step the number
 \footnote{\csname extfootnote#1\endcsname}\fi}
```

This works for me in your example.

[image]